# Data bound object in Kendo UI MVVM

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-mvvm

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the concept of Kendo's MVVM implementation, but... I have a simple Kendo UI Mobile `view` that is data-bound to a view model:

```
var myViewModel = kendo.observable({
    myEntity: null,

    onViewShow: function (e) {
        var bindingEntity = myStaticDataSource[0];
        myViewModel.set("myEntity", bindingEntity);
    }
});
```

`myStaticDataSource` is a static array of "entities" as simple JavaScript objects, with fields like `name` or `description`.

The view and its input fields are bound to the view model:

```
<div data-role="view" data-layout="default" data-model="myViewModel" data-bind="events: { show: onViewShow }">
    <form>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
            <li>
                <label>
                    Name
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: myEntity.name" />
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

When the user changes the input field, the corresponding field (e.g. `name`) is updated in the data-bound view model entity `myEntity`. But: what I would have expected is that the entity in `myStaticDataSource` is updated as well, since I'm not cloning objects. But it isn't! Its value remains on the original value. Why is this? Am I missing something about Kendo's MVVM handling?

Comment: You _are_ cloning it by assigning the element to a variable using `var bindingEntity = myStaticDataSource[0]` and then binding that variable to the view. It's doing exactly what you told it to. The variable `bindingEntity` (i.e. `myEntity`) is being updated, not `myStaticDataSource`.

Comment: @Brett that is not quite true. `var bindingEntity = myStaticDataSource[0]` does not clone the item, the call to kendo `.set()` does as a side-effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a side-effect of Kendo Observable objects and arrays.
When you assign a property to an `ObservableObject` using the `.set()` method, it wants to make that assigned item an observable as well. Your items in `myStaticDataSource` are probably plain JS objects and not Kendo Observables, so Kendo wraps the object into a new `ObservableObject` for you. This means that the objects are no longer the same.

This might make more sense:

```
var items = [{name: "item one"}];
var vm = kendo.observable({item: undefined});
vm.set("item", items[0]);
vm.item === items[0]; // returns FALSE
items[0] instanceof kendo.data.ObservableObject // returns FALSE
vm.item instanceof kendo.data.ObservableObject // returns TRUE


var items = kendo.observable([{name: "item one"}]);
var vm = kendo.observable({item: undefined});
vm.set("item", items[0]);
vm.item === items[0]; // returns TRUE
items[0] instanceof kendo.data.ObservableObject // returns TRUE
vm.item instanceof kendo.data.ObservableObject // returns TRUE
```

The "fix" for this is to do any one of:

---

Make `myStaticDataSource` a Kendo `DataSource`, which will make all the items you put into it a `ObservableObject`.

```
var myStaticDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        {name: "Bob"}
    ]
};
```

---

Make `myStaticDataSource` a Kendo `ObservableArray`, which will make all the items you put into it a `ObservableObject`

```
var myStaticDataSource = kendo.observable([
    {name: "Bob"}
]);
```

---

Make each item in the `myStaticDataSource` array an `ObservableObject`

```
var myStaticDataSource = [
    kendo.observable({name: "Bob"})
];
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the call of `.set()` has the side effect of cloning the object. Now it's clear!